# Why does this total not amount to 1000?

Tags: python, random, simulation

When I run the program below, the total is not 1000. I have no idea what is wrong.

In 1000 tosses of a dice, there were:

- 180 for 1
- 136 for 2
- 121 for 3
- 97 for 4
- 72 for 5
- 60 for 6.

This totals to 666 rolls of the dice.

I am trying to be specific, if there is anything I am not clear about, please let me know. And thanks everyone:)

```
#this is a program that simulate how many times that there will be for every sides of a dice, when I trying to throw it 1,000 times.

from random import randrange

def toss():
    if randrange(6) == 0:
        return "1"
    elif randrange(6) ==1:
        return "2"
    elif randrange(6) ==2:
        return "3"
    elif randrange(6) ==3:
        return "4"
    elif randrange(6) ==4:
        return "5"
    elif randrange(6) ==5:
        return "6"

def roll_dice(n):
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    count3 = 0
    count4 = 0
    count5 = 0
    count6 = 0
    for i in range(n):
        dice = toss()
        if dice == "1":
            count1 = count1 + 1
        if dice == "2":
            count2 = count2 + 1
        if dice == "3":
            count3 = count3 + 1
        if dice =="4":
            count4 = count4 + 1
        if dice == "5":
            count5 = count5 + 1
        if dice == "6":
            count6 = count6 + 1
    print ("In", n, "tosses of a dice, there were", count1, "for 1 and", 

count2, "for 2 and", count3, "for 3 and", count4, "for 4 and", count5, "for
 5 and",count6, "for 6.")

roll_dice(1000)
```

Comment: try chaning it to something like `def toss(): return randrange(6) + 1;` and `for i in range(n): i = toss(); count[i] = count.get(i, 0) + 1;` Just to make my eyes hurt less

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. What have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

You're calling `randrange(6)` in all your `if/elif` tests, so the value is different (it's *random*) and you may end up returning `None` from your `toss` function (and you're missing some counts)

Store `randrange(6)` in a variable, *then* test it.

there are better ways of doing this BTW for instance an equivalent but which works:

```
def toss():
    return str(randrange(6)+1)
```

But there's an entire quicker way using `collections.Counter` and a generator comprehension to generate 1000 values from 1 to 6 at random:

```
import collections
import random
c = collections.Counter(random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(1000))
print(c)
print(sum(c.values()))
```

I get those 2 output lines (first the dict counting the numbers and the total number of rolls):

```
Counter({3: 199, 2: 172, 1: 160, 5: 160, 4: 158, 6: 151})
1000
```

now I have my 1000 values :)

Answer (score 1):

Because it calls the function again in every condition.

```
if randrange(6) == 0:
```

if it's not 0 then it goes on to the second if, where randrange(6) will be called again with a new value.